# Query fails when trying to Increment SQL Row in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm basically trying to increment a row value from being '24' to '25' during runtime. However the query fails and produces me this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Views + 1' to data type int.

Query:

```
update posttable 
set Views = 'ISNULL(Views, 0) + 1' 
where id = '379698'
```

The column is of type `int` and it's not `varchar`. Why does it fail?

Comment: `The Column is int and it's not varchar. Why does it fail?` Because you're assigning a varchar value, delimited by the quotes. The message is even clear in saying the value it's receiving and why it's invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of quotes

```
update posttable set Views=Views + 1 where id='379698'
```

Comment: remove the quotes. You cannot do mathematical operations on a string.